# scala fixed length string format not working for Chinese

Tags: string, scala, format

I'm trying to pad strings to make them have same length using string format, which works well on English strings:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = "this is first"
    val b = "second"
    val c = "third word"

    println(f"$a%-30s" + "|")
    println(f"$b%-30s" + "|")
    println(f"$c%-30s" + "|")
}

// gives:
this is first                 |
second                        |
third word                    |
```

However, when I test it on Chinese strings, this method doesn't work anymore:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = "小伙_6"
    val b = "女网友_6"
    val c = "有期徒刑_6"

    println(f"$a%-30s" + "|")
    println(f"$b%-30s" + "|")
    println(f"$c%-30s" + "|")

// gives:
小伙_6                          |
女网友_6                         |
有期徒刑_6                        |
```

How can I get this work for Chinese strings?

Comment: Your English language example only works of you are printing to a window or terminal using a fixed-width (mono-spaced) font. If I change my IntelliJ font to `aakar`, for example, then the bar characters, `|`, don't line up at all. Perhaps Chinese fonts offer similar options?

Comment: @jwvh Yes you are right. It turns out to be a font issue.